# global $language not working in custom module

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a custom module which I want to check the language code of the current interface language, So I added a helper function to the mymodule.module file.

It didn't work in mymodule when I call it, It returned nothing. But If I added this function to my template.php in the mytheme directory it works like a charm and return the language code for the current interface.

I am guesting that its related to the current weight of the module in the system table, What do you think?

```
function language_code(){
  global $language;
  return $language->language;
}
```

For additional debugging I used `dpm($language);` after defining `global $language;` in mymodule it didn't return the language array.

Comment: Do you unistall/install locale module?try it.

Answer (score 1):

drupal has a function that return default language `language_default` with the below code

```
    function language_default($property = NULL) {
  $language = variable_get('language_default', (object) array('language' => 'en', 'name' => 'English', 'native' => 'English', 'direction' => 0, 'enabled' => 1, 'plurals' => 0, 'formula' => '', 'domain' => '', 'prefix' => '', 'weight' => 0, 'javascript' => ''));
  return $property ? $language->$property : $language;
}
```

I suggest you in `hook_init`(maybe your fuction not called or problem realated to your fuction)  call this function

```
function yourmodulename_init() {
  dsm(language_default());
  global $language;
  dsm($language);
}
```

According [drupal documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/7) , `$language` is global variable , you problem is some strange .

I thnik problem is in your function and method of calling function. by default if you put a function in module and your module enabled(after clear cache) ,the function globaly exist and you can use it everywhere (even in views on anywhere you think).

If `dsm` in `hook_init` return `$language` value  I suggest you test your function

```
function my_language_code(){
  global $language;
  return $language->language;
```

}

in very where you want

```
$lang=my_language_code();
dsm($lang);
```

test this please

Comment: I will check and come back to you.